# can't open same project with multiple location at a time?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made some changes in myapp like change display name.

after that I have copy project to another directory. but it couldn't open it gives error like below image

[image]

it gives error message "Bizz Tamanna.xcodeproj Couldn't load Bizz Tamanna.xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace"

this message is correct I have opened that project from another directory also but this error I got first time before change bundle display name or some change it works perfectly on both location.

When I closed already opened project then it works perfectly.

appreciate for help

Comment: I think both project's parent folder is same. Just copy to desktop and run from there..

Comment: @jpulikkottil parent directory isnot same